# Is there a method to omit nested parentheses in regex?

Tags: php, regex, nested, parentheses

I'm writing a regex function for PHPs' `preg_match_all` to find all `ifs(...)` with all its contents from a string. (In my example I've got only one ifs, as it's not re root of the problem.)

Here's what I've got so far:

Pattern: `/ifs\(.*?\)/i`

String: `=iferror(ifs(OR("foo", "bar"),"a",OR("tar", "scar"),"b",OR("lar"),"d"),"c")`

Current output: `ifs(OR("foo", "bar")`

Expected output: `ifs(OR("foo", "bar"),"a",OR("tar", "scar"),"b",OR("lar"),"d")`

The problem: regex finds first closing parentheses.

Where am I going wrong? And how would you tackle nested parentheses?

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/SgBqbW/1

Comment: this is not possible via regular expressions
, you need some tokenizer and tree of expressions to correctly parse ending parentheses ; try to add in your regexp101 "ungreedy" flag (U) and you will understand

Comment: uh oh.. Did try that, but had high hopes that maybe I am missing something. Unfortunately not... Thanks anyway! Back to drawing board for me it is then. x_x

Comment: Well PCRE is actually capable of matching nested parentheses, but now your problems start once parentheses are contained inside string literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can do this thanks to PHPs capability of [recursive regexps](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php). This is inspired by [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php#111935) on that page:

```
$string = '=iferror(ifs(OR("foo", "bar"),"a",OR("tar", OR("scar", "baa")),"b",OR("lar"),"d"),"c")
blah blah ifs(OR("foo", "bar"),"a") and another one ifs("a", OR("tar", OR("scar", "baa")),"b",OR("lar"),"d")';
$regex = '/ifs(\(((?>[^()]+)|(?-2))*\))/';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [0] => ifs(OR("foo", "bar"),"a",OR("tar", OR("scar", "baa")),"b",OR("lar"),"d")
    [1] => ifs(OR("foo", "bar"),"a")
    [2] => ifs("a", OR("tar", OR("scar", "baa")),"b",OR("lar"),"d") 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/1OKQu)